# Unable to map imported images in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to import a number of images from my img folder and then map through them to display them, however I can't get it display by mapping ,If i use it directly it works.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router'
 /*eslint-disable */
import { image1,image2 } from '../../../../assets/img/'
/*eslint-enable */

export default class Gallery extends Component {
 render() {
 const images = [
  { id: 1, img: {image1} },
  { id: 2, img: 'image2' },
]

const logos = (
  <section>
    <ul className={styles.products}>
    {images.map(img =>
      <li key={img.id} className={styles.productImg}>
        <img src={img.img} />
        <img src={image2} />
      </li>
    )}
    </ul>
  </section>
)

return (
  <div>
    {logos}
  </div>
)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MApping will work, However you need to add one element at a time and change to

```
const images = [
  { id: 1, img: image1 },
  { id: 2, img: image2 },
]
```

```js
class Gallery extends React.Component {
 render() {
 const images = [
  { id: 1, img: 'http://www.gettyimages.co.uk/gi-resources/images/Embed/new/embed2.jpg' },
  { id: 2, img: 'http://www.gettyimages.co.uk/gi-resources/images/Embed/new/embed2.jpg' },
]

const logos = (
  <section>
    <ul >
    {images.map(img =>
      <li key={img.id} >
        <img src={img.img} />
      </li>
    )}
    </ul>
  </section>
)

return (
  <div>
    {logos}
  </div>
)
}
}
ReactDOM.render(<Gallery/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Hi, I am aware that would work but the difficulty I'm having is mapping with my imported images as they're showing as localhost:8080/image1 (returns 404 error) or localhost:8080/[object%20object] (404 not found)

Comment: In that case you can try imports like `import image1from '../../../../assets/img/.image1.jpg'` or `import image2  from '../../../../assets/img/image2.jpg'` and configure your webpackwith `url-loader`